# How to fetch row from two tables in single query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables

```
1>EVENT table columns event_id, time
2>EVENT_TYPE1 table columns ref_event_id
3>EVENT_TYPE2 table columns ref_event_id
```

now what I want to do is to perform a query so that ref_event_id from both tables EVENT_TYPE1 and EVENT_TYPE2 can be compared to EVENT table ,in single query, and results are arranged in ascending order of time.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29 ?

Comment: Both event types in a single row, or `UNION`'ed together?

Answer (score 0):

This creates a single table to join with ordered as you want

```
SELECT combined.* FROM (
  SELECT * from EVENT_TYPE1
   UNION
  SELECT * from EVENT_TYPE2) AS combined
```

I'm a little fuzzy on what you mean by 'Compared to Event table'. You can join the result of this inner select to the Event table on `event_id = ref_event_id` assuming ref_event_id is a foreign key into the event table.

```
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT * from EVENT_TYPE1
      UNION
     SELECT * from EVENT_TYPE2) AS combined 
 JOIN EVENT ON event_id = combined.ref_event_id 
    ORDER BY combined.time ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2 
FROM EVENT a
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT col1, col2 FROM EVENT_TYPE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col1, col2 FROM EVENT_TYPE2) b ON b.col1 = a.col1  <== Comparison
```